# Grails 3.1.2 project by Jenkins: Unknown command-line option '-n'

Tags: grails, jenkins, gradle, grails-3.1

I copy-pasted jenkins job (which works in Grails 2.4.5) but it fails in new Grails 3.1.2 project:

```
Started by user Michal Szulc
Building in workspace <http://jenkins.example.com/job/project-server/ws/>
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > /usr/bin/git config remote.project-server_repository.url http://git.example.pl/scm/es/project-server.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from http://git.example.pl/scm/es/project-server.git
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
using .gitcredentials to set credentials
 > /usr/bin/git config --local credential.helper store --file=/tmp/git6110612657385406031.credentials # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress http://git.example.pl/scm/es/project-server.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/project-server_repository/*
 > /usr/bin/git config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse refs/remotes/project-server_repository/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse refs/remotes/project-server_repository/project-server_repository/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision eb5ef3113a02e6dc325d91ba5cc4b9ee7b935c90 (refs/remotes/project-server_repository/master)
 > /usr/bin/git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git checkout -f eb5ef3113a02e6dc325d91ba5cc4b9ee7b935c90
 > /usr/bin/git rev-list eb5ef3113a02e6dc325d91ba5cc4b9ee7b935c90 # timeout=10
[project-server] $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/com.g2one.hudson.grails.GrailsInstallation/3.1.2/bin/grails -Dgrails.work.dir=<http://jenkins.example.com/job/project-server/ws//target> -Dserver.port=40855 clean --non-interactive --plain-output
Error |
Command [clean] error: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.11-bin.zip'.
Problem with provided build arguments: [-non-interactive, --console, plain]. 
Unknown command-line option '-n'.
Either it is not a valid build option or it is not supported in the target Gradle version.
Not all of the Gradle command line options are supported build arguments.
Examples of supported build arguments: '--info', '-u', '-p'.
Examples of unsupported build options: '--daemon', '-?', '-v'.
Please find more information in the javadoc for the BuildLauncher class. (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Build step 'Build With Grails' marked build as failure
```

If I run `./gradlew clean` or `./gradlew war` in local environment it works perfectly. How to run it by jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure why this situation has happened but I resolved an issue by changing **Build** -> **Build With Grails** -> **Targets**:

```
clean "war api.project-server.pl.war"
```

to:

```
"war api.project-server.pl.war"
```